# SharePoint Alert Automation

Tags: 2016, sharepoint-alerts

We are on SharePoint 2016 OnPrem.

Is there a way to set users up to receive alerts automatically (for specific global lists/libraries) when they onboard to the Organization based on their role programmatically so they do not need to set them up themselves? How can this be automated?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do it would be to set alerts against a group and add that person to a group as part of on-boarding process. This way they will be automatically included in the email alerts.

Comment: Thank you Marek ... I will try this